# Bootstrap 3 form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 to build a contact form and I have the following problem: If submitted empty, the form submits to the same page. If i enter values in the boxes, it will redirect to the homepage. This problem only occurs if I'm using a name="something" attribute for the input boxes. Does anyone have any idea why? HTML is this:

```
      <form class="form" method="post" action="http://localhost/contact">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Nume</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Numele tau...">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Adresa email</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Adresa email...">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="subject">Subiect</label>
          <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subiectul mesajului...">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message">Mesaj</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="5" placeholder="Mesajul tau aici..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Trimite mesajul!</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Use an ACTION parameter in the FORM tag to control the target: `<form class="form" role="form" method="post" action="some_page.php">`

Comment: I added that as well, It points to the correct url, but it's instead displaying the homepage.

Comment: One thing to note: If I remove the name="something" parameter, it works. But I need that to use it with php...

Comment: Maybe You are providing correct data, and Your PHP redirect You to Your homepage after doing something with those data.

Comment: The php is hand written, there's no way of that happening.

Answer (score 0):

You need an action to actually submit the form. The form won't do anything until you add an action to process the form and email it.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="contactform.php">
```

I use a variation of this form, http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-form-to-email.html

Comment: I added that as well, It points to the correct url, but it's instead displaying the homepage. One thing to note: If I remove the name="something" parameter, it works. But I need that to use it with php...

Comment: Have you created a php page?

Comment: Of course. I've integrated this design into a wordpress theme.

Comment: Have you created a php file for the action? i.e. form.php that processes the form and sends an email?

Comment: Yes. I've answered that in my previous comment... Even if I had not created one, it should not default to the homepage. I should have got a 404 error.

Comment: Can you paste your updated code for the form please.

Comment: Thanks...so what is on the contact page? Can you paste the code on that please.